# `1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'user_admin'@'%' to database 'mysql'`

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database

I created an cloud SQL table on Azure. I accessed it using MySQLWorkbench & DbVisualizer. I then wrote a query to create a table as follows:

```
"CREATE TABLE `mysql`.`actual_sales` (
                              `Timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                              `Transaction` INT NOT NULL, 
                              `Item` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
                              `restaurant_ID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);"
```

However, after I ran it, I got the following error: `1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'user_admin'@'%' to database 'mysql'`

I checked the privileges using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`user` WHERE `User` = 'user_admin';
```

and I noticed that `Super_priv`, `Create_tablespace_priv` are set to `N`.

I tried to update them to `Y` with the following:

```
UPDATE `mysql`.`user` SET `Super_priv` = 'Y' WHERE `User` = 'user_admin';
UPDATE `mysql`.`user` SET `Create_tablespace_priv` = 'Y' WHERE `User` = 'user_admin';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SELECT `User`, `Grant_priv` FROM `mysql`.`user`;
```

However, again I got `1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'user_admin'@'%' to database 'mysql'`

What is going on here? How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Have you set the firework&network of your sql server? Like add your public ip address to your allowed list.

Comment: Yes I did, there was an option to add client IP so I added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not create tables under the default database `mysql`. You need to crate a new database.

```
create database test1;

use test1;

CREATE TABLE `test1`.`actual_sales` (
                              `Timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                              `Transaction` INT NOT NULL, 
                              `Item` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
                              `restaurant_ID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
```

[image]